# How to remove vertical space between two detail bands of ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two Detail Bands in my ireport. When I run the report it shows extra vertical space between two bands. How I can remove this extra vertical space?

Answer (score 2):

1. reduce the size of elements in details bands
2. right click on bands -> Stretch To Content
3. in your elements properties set "positionType" to float and "isStretchWithOverflow" to true

Or if you are sure that your report will not have more that one page : 
set "isIgnorePagination" to true in your report properties

Answer (score 1):

This might help!

I had this problem exactly and had two things to do to fix it. After searching for a while I think there can many different things that add space between the detail band and the column footer band.

First, there is an attribute isFloatColumnFooter in element jasperReport of your xml design that you should set to "true" if you want the column footer to directly follow the details band.

Second, I also noticed that the summary band is placed BEFORE the column footer band in the last page of a report. Consequently, you may need to set the height of the summary band to "0" if you want your column footer band to be right after the details band.

By Marc

Answer (score 0):

You have to set band property:
   Split type: Immediate

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to select the report and check the option Float Column footer in the report's properties nothing else. It eliminates the space between the detail and the column footer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use subreports, then the space may have been added by the margins in the *jasperReport* tag of your subreports.

I was using Jaspersoft Studio and removed them via "Page format", but the space between the detail bands stayed there, until I edited the XML itself and set the topMargin and bottomMargin to 0, that removed the space.

Answer (score 0):

In XML tab 
change this code:

```
<detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch>
```

And set `height=20`

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch>
```

It will work.

Answer (score -2):

set band height to 0 will help.